# Reading a file from a folder when it gets created using nodejs

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, ember.js

Following operations are going to take place :

1. A text file is created using a java program and it gets stored in a folder
2. The file needs to be read and displayed in the text box which is present in the browser UI.
3. For this to happen, the java script needs to check the folder till the text file becomes available and then read it and display it in the text box.

How will the javascript come to know when the text file is available in the folder and how is it going to read it and display it.
We are using Nodejs as the container and Ember Java for the web framework

Comment: The Javascript on the client browser cannot ever be aware of filesystem changes on the server by itself.  You need to have a thread on the server listening for filesystem change events, and an open AJAX connection from the client to the server. When the filesystem listener detects the file a notification is sent to the client.

Comment: All you need is an AJAX call with a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if you run Ember locally rather than served from a web server.

1. Create an in-repo addon in your Ember app. It will have Node context.
2. Have the addon watch the folder for changes. Read the file when it's available
3. Have the addon run a web server that responds with file contents when it's available.
4. Configure your app for long polling the web server.

If you do need to server the app from a web server, then you're out of luck. You can try running a desktop app on the computer that watches the folder for changes then sends the file contents to the server. Then the app can request the file from the server. That's more elaborate.